# Python- iterate through table of addresses, geolocate with function, copy lat/long to row?

Tags: python, geolocation, arcpy

I have a table of addresses, and I need my Python script to use my Google API geolocate function to return lat/long coordinates for each and add to a new field in the same row for each address.  The geocode function works fine- I just can't get the script to iterate through each row of the table, add the address to the function, and then copy the output lat/long to the field in the same row.  here's what I have:

```
import urllib, json, time, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/GIS/addr.dbf"

#sets variables, adds new field to hold lat/long coordinates
fc = 'addr.dbf'
field1 = 'address'
field2 = 'loc'
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field2, "TEXT")


#function that uses Google API to geolocate- this part works consistently
def geolocate(address, 
api="key_here",delay=4):
  base = r"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
  addP = "address=" + address.replace(" ","+")
  gUrl = base + addP + "&key=" + api
  response = urllib.urlopen(gUrl)
  jres = response.read()
  jData = json.loads(jres)
  if jData['status'] == 'OK':
    resu = jData['results'][0]
    finList = [resu['formatted_address'],resu['geometry']['location'] 
    ['lat'],resu['geometry']['location']['lng']]
  else:
    finList = [None,None,None]
  time.sleep(delay)
  return finList


#adds address field as text to geolocate in function, adds output lat/long 
#(indexed locations 0 and 1 from the finList output)
##this is the part that doesn't work!
geo = geolocate(address = field1)
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, [field1, field2])
for row in cursor:
  field2 = geo[0], geo[1]
  cursor.updateRow(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the geolocate function with the string 'address'

```python
field1 = 'address'
geo = geolocate(address = field1)
```

You want to call geolocate with the actual address, which means you need to do it within your loop that is iterating through the cursor. So it should be something like:

```
fields = [field1, field2])
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        address = row[0]
        geo = geolocate(address = address)
        row[1] = geo[0], geo[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Note: I used the cursor from the data access module which was introduced in ArcGIS 10.1. I also used the 'with' syntax for the cursor so that it automatically handles deleting the cursor.